# How do I link two nodes within pipewire.conf?

Tags: linux, configuration-managment, pipewire

I'm working on a project which deals with routing audio via PipeWire. I need it to be WM agnostic, so I could either write the PipeWire configuration in a shell script and have a SystemD service for it, or I could write it into pipewire.conf, preferably the latter.

The `link-factory` factory seemingly has no documentation (https://docs.pipewire.org/page_module_link_factory.html) apart from this tidbit (According to the limited knowledge I have): https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Config-PipeWire#making-objects

An example of a working command, just for reference:

`pw-link -d alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo:capture_FR Project-Out:input_FR`